# Finding index of array

Tags: java

Could someone explain to me why is the result is 6? Thanks

```
String[] s = { "A", "B", "C", "D" };
String b = "ABRACADABRA";
int i = s.length - 1;
System.out.print( b.indexOf( s[ i ] ) );
```

I understand s length is 4, so i = 3, but then what does s[i] mean?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Java strings and arrays are [0-indexed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-based_numbering). This means that the first element has index 0, the second element has index 1, etc...

So `s[3]` means the *fourth* element of `s` which is `D`. The expression `b.indexOf("D")` is 6 because `D` is the *seventh* letter in `ABRACADABRA` and so it is at index 6.

Comment: Since the index of D in String b is 6th it print out 6? Thank you !

Answer (score 2):

The i means the index
so in s, you have

```
i|s

0|A
1|B
2|C
3|D
```

so in the brackets, you are just giving it the index of the value you want.
so s[3] gives you D.
Then you are saying to find the index of the value you give it and you gave it the values 'D', so it looks for where 'D' is in ABRACADABRA. So remember that arrays start counting at 0, so

```
0|A
1|B
2|R
3|A
4|C
5|A
6|D
....
```

The index where D is located is 6.

Answer (score 2):

i is the array index. In an array the index always starts with 0. which means that If you want to get the data at the first position u need to do s[0] which gives u 'A' .

its always - 1 from the actual position you want to get.